# Flask disable CSRF in unittest

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

In my projects __init__.py I have this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
CsrfProtect(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

My development config file looks like:

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = True
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True
SECRET_KEY = 'supersecretkey'
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'project.db')
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

And in my unittest setUp I have this:

```
from project import app, db

class ExampleTest(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://'
        self.app = app.test_client()
        db.create_all()
```

In theory, setting WTF_CSRF_ENABLED to False here should prevent CSRF for the unit tests, however I'm still getting CSRF errors if I do a POST while unit testing. I think it is because I have already called CsrfProtect(app) while WTF_CSRF_ENABLED is True (when I import app, it is called). If I set WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False in the config file, it works as expected.

Is there anyway I can disable CSRF after it has already been enabled? Or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: I think once you import app that code is run, therefore it will run with your default config, so after that when you do your test it will not matter that you are overriting the config

Comment: Yeah, that's my thought as well. I'm hoping there is some way to disable it after the fact, maybe not through app.config, but something like StopCsrfProtect(app) or something. But that's probably wishful thinking.

Comment: I guess the easiest workaround is to just run it with CSRF disabled when you are testing.

Comment: I could do that, but I'm worried it might mess up any integration testing. I would either need to remember to change the config file back and forth when running unit tests, or risk not seeing real csrf errors while developing (forget to put a hidden_tag in jinja template or something). Hmm....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking at the code for csrf_protect, it checks app.config['WTF_CSRF_METHODS'] every time a request comes in to see if this request type should be CSRF protected. By default the protected methods are:

```
app.config.setdefault('WTF_CSRF_METHODS', ['POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH'])
```

Because it actually checks the app.config every time, simply changing this to an empty list in my unit tests setUp resolves the issue:

```
from project import app, db

class ExampleTest(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['WTF_CSRF_METHODS'] = []  # This is the magic
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://'
        self.app = app.test_client()
        db.create_all()
```

Alternetly, it does register the csrf protection with app.before_request(), so I think it may be possible to unregister it by modifying the [before request functions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Flask.before_request_funcs). But I think going that route would be more likely to see problems on future updates.

Comment: Create a Custom Class extending unit tests and override this configuration and use it in other test classes

Answer (score 31):

You can disable it using the config variable `WTF_CSRF_ENABLED`,

for example

```
class TestConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
    WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False
    ...
```

or `app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False`

See also [flask-WTF documentation](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/534e1734b86c2f0907af131c11b981e6146ca57c/docs/config.rst)

Comment: For my situation, the code looks like: myapplication.app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False

Answer (score 3):

It wasn't too hard to keep the `csrf_token` if that is an option. I was able to successfully log into an application that used a `csrf_token` using some regular expressions and using the login function that is found in the [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/#logging-in-and-out) about testing.

```
def login(self, username, password):
    rv = self.client.get('/login')
    m = re.search(b'(<input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value=")([-A-Za-z.0-9]+)', rv.data)

    return self.client.post('/login', data=dict(
        userName=username,
        password=password,
        csrf_token=m.group(2).decode("utf-8")
    ), follow_redirects=True)
```

So what I have done here is made the `csrf_token` be apart of the second capture group. This could easily be used to find a token all over the application.

Comment: This regex fails a lot for me. Updated and consistently working: `m = re.search(b'<input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="(.*)">', rv.data)` and just decode `m.group(1).decode("utf-8")` since there's no reason to capture the first group. You were missing an underscore, but there's no reason to define the valid characters since the final `"` terminates the capture group properly anyway. I would prefer to just turn off csrf, but it seems like that causes the templates to fail for me now. I don't at all get why.