# Unittest Flask-App CSRF-token missing after Post-Request

Tags: unit-testing, csrf, wtforms

When unittesting my flask-app and sending post-requests with a Testclient I find a form.error that the CSRF token is missing.

I have been to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624060/flask-disable-csrf-in-unittest) and to [this](https://flowfx.de/blog/disable-csrf-validation-when-unit-testing-a-flask-app/) post, also read the documentation, however I still cant get my Problem solved.

How the CSRF-Protection is created:

```py
class Routes:
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = WebserverConfig().secret_key
    CSRFProtect().init_app(__app)
```

The view to be tested:

```py
@__app.route("/settings", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def settings():
    form = SettingsForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            Routes.__reqhandler.put_settings(form=form)
            return redirect(url_for("settings"))
        if form.errors != {}:
            Routes.__reqhandler.error_put_settings(form=form)
    data = Routes.__prepdata.prep_settings()
    return render_template("settings.html", form=form, data=data)
```

The template which contains the form:

```html
<form method="POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="text-center">
      <h3>Einstellungen</h3>
    </div>
    {{ form.intervall.label }} 
    {{ form.intervall(id="intervall", class="form-control", placeholder=data["intervall"])}}
</form>
```

The fixture creating the testclient:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    app = Routes().get_app()
    app.config["WTF_CSRF_METHODS"] = []
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client
```

The test:

```py
def test_settings_valid_intervall(client):
    res = client.post("settings", data={"intervall": "00:01:00"}, follow_redirects=True)
    assert b'value="00:01:00' in res.data
```

When printing the data (`print(res.data)` an alert (created with a flash if there are errors in a form) with the info that "The CSRF token is missing" is sent. What am I missing to tell  `form.validate_on_submit` to not check if a valid CSRF-token was passed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by not only emptying the list of the `WTF_CSRF_METHODS` but also disabling CSRF within the fixture that creates the client:

```py
app.config["WTF_CSRF_ENABLED"] = False
```